# Confidence score for machine learning with SciKit Learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, face-recognition

I have followed an example of applying SciKit Learning's machine learning to facial recognition.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-face-recognition-py

I have been able to adapt the example to my own data successfully.      However, I am lost on one point:

after preparing the data, training the model, ultimately, you end up with the line:
**Y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_pca)**

This produces a vector of predictions, one per face.
What I can't figure out is how to get any confidence measurement to correspond with that.

The classification method is a forced choice, so that each face passed in MUST be classified as one of the known faces, even if it isn't even close.

How can I get a number per face that will reflect how well the result matches the known face?

Comment: `clf.predict_proba()`?

Comment: "print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=range(n_classes)))"

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the `.predict_proba()` method of the `scikit-learn` estimators. It returns the probabilities of possible outcomes instead of a single prediction.

The example you are referring to is using an [`SVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC). It is a little special in regard to this function as it states:

> The model need to have probability information computed at training time: fit with attribute `probability` set to True.

So, if you are using the same model as in the example, instantiate it with:

```
SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced', probability=True)
```

and use `.predict_proba()` instead of `.predict()`:

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test_pca)
```

This returns an array of shape *(n_samples, n_classes)*, i.e. the probabilities for each class for each sample. Accessing the probabilities for class `k` could then be done by calling `y_pred[k]` for example.

Comment: Thanks very much.      I ALMOST have it working now.      The only remaining issue I have is that the size of the result is slightly smaller than makes sense.        I have 62 classes, but I am getting back an Nx60 result, where N is the number  of images.        I checked if there were 2 classes missing from the training data set, but none of them are empty.      Any suggestion how the # of classes could be reduced?       I have confirmed they are all unique as well.

Comment: After you have fit the model, check `SVC.classes_` to see which labels have been identified by the estimator. Compare the result with the classes of your final dataset that is passed to the estimator and see if you can find any clue. If what you are saying is right, it will return 60 labels and you should see what is missing.